# Add normal curve and horizontal box-plot to already tabulated survey data

Tags: r, charts, ggplot2, survey

I have some already tabulated survey data imported in a data frame and can making bar charts from it with ggplot.

```
  X                X.1 X.2
3 Less than 1 year       7
4        1-5 years      45
5       6-10 years      84
6      11-15 years     104
7 16 or more years     249
```

`ggplot(responses[3:7,], aes(y=X.2, factor(X))) + geom_bar()`

I would like to overlay a normal curve on the bar chart, and a horizontal box and whisker plot below that but I am unsure about the correct way to do this without the individual observations, it should be possible... I think. The example output I am trying to emulate is here: http://t.co/yOqRmOj5

I look forward to learning a new trick for this if there is one, or if anyone else had encountered it.

Comment: I'm assuming it's the calculation of the parameters for the normal distribution curve that are hanging you up. If I remember rightly, your best estimates for the mean and variance from a histogram distribution come by assuming each observation is in the middle of each class. In fact, that's all you can assume from histogram data for any derived statistic.

Comment: @ChrisNash but this is not a histogram binning; it is a set of arbitrary, non-uniform, non-spanning cut points.

Comment: Agreed. I noticed in the original PDF some of the categories weren't even numeric.

Comment: I'm glad someone else was disturbed by a normal curve over the categories "yes" and "no", or categories that included "NGO", "corporate", and "other". I'm afraid that they made a normal curve using an (arbitrary) underlying integer coding of the groups. With nominal data, it is useless; with ordinal (binned numerical) data, it is misleadingly wrong.

Comment: @Brian Diggs, Thanks for confirming some of my confusion about the original document and the odd task I assigned myself.

Answer (score 6):

To save anyone else having to download the 134 page PDF, here is an example of the graph referenced in the question.

[image: http://coast.gkss.de/staff/storch/pdf/CliSci2008.pdf, page 16]

In this example, the data is from a Likert scale, and so the original data can be extrapolated and a normal curve and boxplot is at least interpretable. However, there are plots where the horizontal scale is nominal. Normal curves make no sense in these cases.

Your question is about an ordinal scale. Just from this summarized data, it is not reasonable to try and make a normal curve.  You could treat each entry as located at the center point of its range (0.5 years, 3 years, 8 years, etc.), but there is no way to reasonably assign a value for the highest group (and worse, it is your largest, so its contribution is not insignificant).  You must have the original data to make any reasonable approximation.

Comment: Sorry about the file size of the PDF.. The survey did not ask the ordinal number of years (and this is just an example question) but when the paper was tabulated it was just a count of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a density estimation based on the data that you have, then the `oldlogspline` function in the `logspline` package can fit density estimates to interval censored data:

```
mymat <- cbind( c(0,1,5.5,10.5, 15.5), c(1,5.5,10.5, 15.5, Inf) )[rep(1:5, c(7,45,84,104,249)),]

library(logspline)

fit <- oldlogspline(interval=mymat[mymat[,2] < 100,],
    right=mymat[ mymat[,2]>100, 1], lbound=0)
fit2 <- oldlogspline.to.logspline(fit)

hist( mymat[,1]+0.5, breaks=c(0,1,5.5,10.5,15.5,60), main='', xlab='Years')
plot(fit2, add=TRUE, col='blue')
```

If you want a normal distribution, then the `survreg` function in the `survival` package will fit interval censored data:

```
library(survival)

mymat2 <- mymat
mymat2[ mymat2>100 ] <- NA

fit3 <- survreg( Surv(mymat2[,1], mymat2[,2], ,type='interval2') ~ 1, 
    dist='gaussian', control=survreg.control(maxiter=100) )
curve( dnorm(x, coef(fit3), fit3$scale), from=0, to=60, col='green', add=TRUE)
```

Though a different distribution may fit better:

```
fit4 <- survreg( Surv(mymat2[,1]+.01, mymat2[,2], ,type='interval2') ~ 1,
    dist='weibull', control=survreg.control(maxiter=100) )
curve( dweibull(x, scale=exp(coef(fit4)), shape=1/fit4$scale), 
    from=0, to=60, col='red', add=TRUE)
```

You could also fit a discrete distribution using `fitdistr` in `MASS`:

```
library(MASS)
tmpfun <- function(x, size, prob) {
    ifelse(x==0, dnbinom(0,size,prob),
    ifelse(x < 5, pnbinom(5,size,prob)-pnbinom(0,size,prob),
    ifelse(x < 10, pnbinom(10,size,prob)-pnbinom(5,size,prob),
    ifelse(x < 15, pnbinom(15,size,prob)-pnbinom(10,size,prob),
        pnbinom(15,size,prob, lower.tail=FALSE)))))
}

fit5 <- fitdistr( mymat[,1], tmpfun, start=list(size=6, prob=0.28) )
lines(0:60, dnbinom(0:60, fit5$estimate[1], fit5$estimate[2]), 
    type='h', col='orange')
```

If you wanted something a little more fuzz, such that 5.5 years could have been reported as either 5 or 6 years, and missing or I don't knows could be used to some degree (with some assumptions), then the EM algorithm could be used to estimate parameters (but this is a lot more complicated and you need to specify your assumptions in how the actual values would translate to observed values).

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to look at that data. Since it is constrained by design to be integer valued, perhaps fitting a Poisson or Negative Binomial distribution might be more sensible. I think you should ponder the fact that the X values in the data you present are somewhat arbitrary. There appears to be no good reason to think that 3 is the most appropriate value for the lowest category. Why not 1?

And then, of course, you need to explain what that data refers to. It does not look to be at all Normal or even Poisson distributed. It is very left skewed and there are not a lot of left skewed distributions in common usage (despite there being an infinite number of possible such distributions.

If you just wanted to demonstrate how non-Normal this data is even ignoring the fact that you are fitting a trucated version of a Normal distribution, then take a look at this exercise in plotting:

```
 barp <- barplot( dat$X.2)
 barp  
# this is what barplot returns and is then used as the x-values for a call to lines.
     [,1]
[1,]  0.7
[2,]  1.9
[3,]  3.1
[4,]  4.3
[5,]  5.5
 lines(barp, 1000*dnorm(seq(3,7), 7,2))
```